# Changing a UserControl's Default Event Handler

Tags: wpf

I've just created a WPF User Control and i noticed that the default event when you double click the control in Xaml editor is the Loaded Event. In this case it should be the Click event. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: what, to change the default added event?  I doubt it.

Comment: How do third party controls do it?

Comment: I see. I haven't tried with WPF but for Windows Forms it used to be DefaultEventAttribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the DefaultEventAttribute:

```
[DefaultEvent("MouseDown")]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl{ ...
```